# How to compare lists without using set() ? Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get common elements from 2 lists.
I can't use set() for lists with repeatable objects because happens this:

```
list1=set([5, 5, 5])
list2=set([5, 5])
list3=list1.intersection(list2)
print(list3) ---> {5}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: use `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 4):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = [5,5,5,4]
list2 = [5,5,4,4]

result = Counter(list1) & Counter(list2) # & is intersection


>>> result
Counter({5: 2, 4: 1})
>>> list(result.elements())
[4, 5, 5]
```